# Durian Jam (Pectin ratio)

Tags: canning, jam, durian

My friend and I have a tradition of giving each other unspeakably horrible presents on each other's half birthday. I want him to be able to enjoy the delicious taste - and smell - of durian all year long, so I want to make my own jam using Durian. I've canned before (always with store-bought pectin and using slightly-modified versions of the recipes provided with the pectin). I'd rather this be as good as I can possibly make it without too much experimentation (durian is not cheap where I live), so what ratio of pectin to durian should I try to hit?

Comment: Brave of you to accept the horrific smell in your own kitchen while preparing the jam. I wonder if it'll even carry over to a product cooked that much, you may wind up punking yourself here.

Comment: I have a propane-powered burner I can set up outside. The chance that cooking will "purify" the durian scent isn't something I've considered - the same friend bought me durian-filled mochi, which was vile b/c the scent migrated from the filling into the dough, so capturing the scent properly could be a problem.

Comment: Does the burner put out enough heat to effectively can using a standard water-bath method? Even if it does, I don't know how volatile durian's aromatic composition is; as far as I know it's often used fresh or pureed and only slightly cooked, even in things like those mochi. If you're cooking it enough to create a stable jam then you might burn off a lot of the aromatic compounds. (Given how intense it is I bet the product will still be funky, but you yourself are gonna have to deal with the full-strength no-holds-barred version.)

Comment: The burner's about 1-1.5 ft in diameter, so it should be hot enough to cook it. I hope I can actually seal the jars indoors  without too much skunk, but failing that the outside burner is plenty powerful.